# How to properly write SQL statement to work with DataGridView in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

My SQL Query works perfectly in Query Builder

```
SELECT SUM(calories) AS calories, date
FROM food
GROUP BY date
```

[image]

However when I try to populate DataGridView I get the following error:

> Additional information: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

It appears that I have to include all columns in my SQL statement for it to work but I have not found a way to do it because I need the total value of 'calories' for each 'date'.

I am attaching more pictures of the database, so it is clear how its structured:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you use as DataSource for your DataGridView? A DataTable?

Comment: Yes. I managed to solve it. You just have to SELECT everything and give your columns a COUNT function for example.